# Construct dependent random variables which converge to standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

I'm asked to construct dependent random variables $X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k=1}^N X_k$$

converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. I honestly don't know where to start. Should I approach the problem with identically distributed variables?

Comment: Why downvote without stating the reason? I'll be happy to restate the question or include more details if needed.

Comment: A possible trick is to take $Y_i$ i.i.d. and, say, Gaussian (to simplify), and write $X_i = (Y_i+Y_{i+1})/2$. You would need to check that the $X_i$ are identicaly distributed, not independent, and that they satify a CLT. For a bonus, compare the variance of the $X_i$ with the variance of the limiting Gaussian.

Comment: @D.Thomine I thought about that too, but I was not sure if the problem is stated in the way that *all* random variables should be dependent! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your interpretation is wrong. We say that $(X_n)$ is dependent if it is not independent. Also the phrase 'all random variables are dependent' does not have a precise meaning.

Comment: It's a strange question.
Is it possible you were actually asked something more like this?
Find a deterministic sequence $x_{k}$ satisfying 
$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} 1_{x_{k}<y} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{y}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz$ for all $y$?

Comment: @Ali Didn't you suggest a telescope sum yesterday? Why did you remove it? Its beautiful.

Comment: @Ali The exact question was *Find a sequence $X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, of dependent, real-valued random variables, such that $N^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^N X_k$ converges to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in distribution as $N \rightarrow \infty$*.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(X_1,X_1,X_2,X_3,...)$ where $\{X_n\}$ is i.i.d with standard nomal distribution. This sequence is not independent. [ See my comment above].

Comment: Is it also fine to choose $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $X_k = (\sqrt(k) - \sqrt(k-1))X_1$ for $k \geq 2$? This will lead to a telescope sum.